# How to calculate and plot a "beta-delta discounting model"?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

**My code for getting a proper plot in R does not seem to work (I am new to R and I am having difficulties with coding).**

Basically, using the concept of temporal discounting in the form of beta-delta model, we are supposed to calculate the  subjective value for $10 at every delay from 0 to 365.

The context of the homework is that we have to account for the important exception that if a reward is IMMEDIATE, there’s no discount, but if it occurs at any delay there’s both an exponential discount and a delay penalty.

I created a variable called **BetaDeltaValuesOf10**, which is 366 elements long and represents the subjective value for $10 at each delay from 0 to 365.

The code needs to have the following properties using **for-loops** and an **if-else statement**:

1) IF the delay is 0, the  subjective value is the objective magnitude (and should be saved to the appropriate element of **BetaDeltaValuesOf10**.

2) OTHERWISE, calculate the subjective value at the exponentially discounted rate, assuming  = .98 and apply a delay penalty of .8, then save it to the appropriate element of **BetaDeltaValuesOf10**.

The standard code given to us to help us in creating the code is as follows:

```
BetaDeltaValuesOf10 = 0

Delays = 0:365
```

Code(Equation) to get subjective value/preference using exponential discounting model:

```
ExponentialDecayValuesOf10 = .98^Delays*10
```

**0.98** is the discount rate which ranges between 0 and 1.

**Delays** is the number of time periods in the future when the later reward will be delivered

**10** is the subjective value of $10

Code(Equation) to get subjective value using beta-delta model:

```
0.8*0.98^Delays*10
```

**0.8** is the delay penalty

The code I came up with in trying to satisfy the above mentioned properties is as follows:

```
for(t in 1:length(Delays)){BetaDeltaValuesOf10 = 0.98^0*10

if(BetaDeltaValuesOf10 == 0){0.98^t*10}

else {0.8*0.98^t*10}
}
```

So, I tried the code and did not get any error. But, when I try to plot the outcome of the code, my plot comes up blank.

To plot I used the code:

```
plot(BetaDeltaValuesOf10,type = 'l', ylab = 'DiscountedValue')
```

I believe that my code is actually faulty and that is why I am not getting a proper outcome for my plot. 
Please let me know of the amendments to the code and if the community needs any clarification, I will try to clarify as soon as I can.

Comment: In your `for` loop, you do some calculations (e.g., `0.98^t*10`) but you don't actually save this result of these calculations.  You need something like `if(x==0) result <- 10 else result <- 11`.  (There may be more issues, this is just the most obvious one.)

Comment: Thank you Dan, I tried fixing the code based on your recommendations. It may have fixed some things but I am still not getting any outcome for the r plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result <- double(length=366)
delays <- 0:365

val     <- 10
delta   <- 0.98
penalty <- 0.8

for(t in seq_along(delays)) {
    result[t] <- val * delta^delays[t] * penalty^(delays[t]>0)
}

plot(x=delays, y=result, pch=20)
```